# How to deal with impurity with mouse event, on a functional approach

Tags: javascript, events, functional-programming, mouse

I was having some trouble trying to figure out how FP works with something like mouse events.
This is an example on how to use mousemove event.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script>
    let mouseObject = {};
    const mouseFn = () => mouseObject;
    const onMove = ev => {
      mouseObject = {x:ev.x, y:ev.y}
    };
    document.addEventListener('mousemove',onMove);
    const loop = (fn) => {
      console.log(fn());
      requestAnimationFrame(() => loop(fn));
    }
    loop(mouseFn);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see on the code I'm adding a listener and then create a loop with requestAnimationFrame.

What I don't like about the code is that on "onMove" function I'm directly modifying mouseObject and also on "mouseFn" I'm returning the mouseObject, which is not pass as a parameter to the function.

But I don't see any better way to do this and to have mouseObject updated inside the loop

Comment: why don't you just pass `{x:ev.x, y:ev.y}` to the function that needs/processes this value? Why all that ceremony?

Comment: How do you pass the object to the function?.

You have to notice that the object is changing every time the mouse move

Comment: Search for [functional reactive programming](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=functional+reactive+programming). [Here's a good place to start](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) for JS.